# What should be the terminating condition for this implementation of the 15-puzzle problem?

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to implement a solution for outputting the sequence of moves for a [15-puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle) problem in Python. This is part of an optional assignment for a MOOC. The problem statement is given at [this link](https://www.coursera.org/learn/what-is-a-proof/supplement/eSLLd/bonus-track-finding-the-sequence-of-moves).

I have a version of the program (given below) which performs valid transitions.

I am first identifying the neighbors of the empty cell (represented by 0) and putting them in a list. Then, I am randomly choosing one of the neighbors from the list to perform swaps with the empty cell. All the swaps are accumulated in a different list to record the sequence of moves to solve the puzzle. This is then outputted at the end of the program.

However, the random selection of numbers to make the swap with the empty cell is just going on forever. To avoid "infinite" (very long run) of loops, I have limited the number of swaps to 30 for now.

```
from random import randint
def find_idx_of_empty_cell(p):
    for i in range(len(p)):
        if p[i] == 0:
            return i

def pick_random_neighbour_idx(neighbours_idx_list):
    rand_i = randint(0, len(neighbours_idx_list)-1)
    return neighbours_idx_list[rand_i]

def perform__neighbour_transposition(p, tar_idx, src_idx):
    temp = p[tar_idx]
    p[tar_idx] = p[src_idx]
    p[src_idx] = temp

def solve_15_puzzle(p):
    standard_perm = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,0]
    neighbours_idx_list = []
    moves_sequence = []
    empty_cell_idx = find_idx_of_empty_cell(p)
    previous_empty_cell_idx = empty_cell_idx

    while (not(p == standard_perm) and len(moves_sequence) < 30):
        if not (empty_cell_idx in [0,4,8,12]):
            neighbours_idx_list.append(empty_cell_idx - 1)
        if not (empty_cell_idx in [3,7,11,15]):
            neighbours_idx_list.append(empty_cell_idx + 1)
        if not (empty_cell_idx in [0,1,2,3]):
            neighbours_idx_list.append(empty_cell_idx - 4)
        if not (empty_cell_idx in [12,13,14,15]):
            neighbours_idx_list.append(empty_cell_idx + 4)

        if previous_empty_cell_idx in neighbours_idx_list:
            neighbours_idx_list.remove(previous_empty_cell_idx)

        chosen_neighbour_idx = pick_random_neighbour_idx(neighbours_idx_list)
        moves_sequence.append(p[chosen_neighbour_idx])
        perform__neighbour_transposition(p, empty_cell_idx, chosen_neighbour_idx)
        previous_empty_cell_idx = empty_cell_idx
        empty_cell_idx = chosen_neighbour_idx
        neighbours_idx_list = []

    if (p == standard_perm):
        print("Solution: ", moves_sequence)
```

For the below invocation of the method, the expected output is `[15, 14, 10, 13, 9, 10, 14, 15]`.

```
solve_15_puzzle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 13, 9, 11, 12, 10, 14, 15, 0])
```

Comment: Please create a tag "15-puzzle" for this question. I think it is required, but I do not have the necessary privilege to do so.

Comment: The 15-puzzle has `(4*4)!/2` (i.e. 10,461,394,944,000) valid configurations; just random walking waiting to stumble in the solution to solve it is going to take a while :-) ... note also that "most difficult" configurations require minimum 80 single-swap moves to solve

Comment: @6502 this seems like searching for a needle in a haystack. How should I proceed then?

Comment: Added an explanation; not posting the code because it's a fun thing to experiment with ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 15-tiles problem is harder as it may seem at a first sight.

Computing the best (shortest) solution is a difficult problem and it has been proved than finding the optimal solution as N increases is NP-hard.

Finding a (non-optimal) solution is much easier. A very simple algorithm that can be made to work for example is:

- Define a "distance" of the current position as the sum of the [manhattan
  distances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) of every tile from the position you want it to be
- Start from the given position and make some random moves
- If the distance after the moves improves or stays the same then keep the changes, otherwise undo them and return to the starting point.

This kind of algorithm could be described as a multi-step stochastic hill-climbing approach and is able to solve the 15 puzzle (just make sure to allow enough random moves to be able to escape a local minimum).

Python is probably not the best language to attack this problem, but if you use PyPy implementation you can get solutions in reasonable time.

My implementation finds a solution for a puzzle that has been mixed up with 1000 random moves in seconds, for example:

```
(1, 5, 43, [9, [4, 10, 14, 11, 15, 3, 8, 1, 13, None, 9, 7, 12, 2, 5, 6]])
(4, 17, 41, [9, [4, 10, 14, 11, 15, 3, 8, 1, 12, None, 6, 2, 5, 13, 9, 7]])
(7, 19, 39, [11, [4, 10, 14, 11, 15, 3, 1, 2, 12, 6, 8, None, 5, 13, 9, 7]])
(9, 54, 36, [5, [4, 14, 3, 11, 15, None, 10, 2, 12, 6, 1, 8, 5, 13, 9, 7]])
(11, 60, 34, [10, [4, 14, 3, 11, 15, 10, 1, 2, 12, 6, None, 8, 5, 13, 9, 7]])
(12, 93, 33, [14, [4, 14, 11, 2, 15, 10, 3, 8, 12, 6, 1, 7, 5, 13, None, 9]])
(38, 123, 31, [11, [4, 14, 11, 2, 6, 10, 3, 8, 15, 12, 1, None, 5, 13, 9, 7]])
(40, 126, 30, [13, [15, 6, 4, 2, 12, 10, 11, 3, 5, 14, 1, 8, 13, None, 9, 7]])
(44, 172, 28, [10, [15, 4, 2, 3, 12, 6, 11, 8, 5, 10, None, 14, 13, 9, 1, 7]])
(48, 199, 23, [11, [15, 6, 4, 3, 5, 12, 2, 8, 13, 10, 11, None, 9, 1, 7, 14]])
(61, 232, 22, [0, [None, 15, 4, 3, 5, 6, 2, 8, 1, 12, 10, 14, 13, 9, 11, 7]])
(80, 276, 20, [10, [5, 15, 4, 3, 1, 6, 2, 8, 13, 10, None, 7, 9, 12, 14, 11]])
(105, 291, 19, [4, [9, 1, 2, 4, None, 6, 8, 7, 5, 15, 3, 11, 13, 12, 14, 10]])
(112, 313, 17, [9, [1, 6, 2, 4, 9, 8, 3, 7, 5, None, 14, 11, 13, 15, 12, 10]])
(113, 328, 16, [15, [1, 6, 2, 4, 9, 8, 3, 7, 5, 15, 11, 10, 13, 12, 14, None]])
(136, 359, 15, [4, [1, 6, 2, 4, None, 8, 3, 7, 9, 5, 11, 10, 13, 15, 12, 14]])
(141, 374, 12, [15, [1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 6, 7, 10, 9, 5, 12, 11, 13, 15, 14, None]])
(1311, 385, 11, [14, [1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 5, 7, 10, 9, 6, 11, 12, 13, 15, None, 14]])
(1329, 400, 10, [13, [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 7, 10, 9, 5, 11, 12, 13, None, 15, 14]])
(1602, 431, 9, [4, [1, 2, 3, 4, None, 6, 8, 7, 9, 5, 11, 10, 13, 15, 14, 12]])
(1707, 446, 8, [5, [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, None, 7, 8, 9, 5, 15, 12, 13, 10, 14, 11]])
(1711, 475, 7, [12, [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 15, 12, None, 13, 14, 11]])
(1747, 502, 6, [8, [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5, 7, 8, None, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 11]])
(1824, 519, 5, [14, [1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 6, 7, 8, 5, 10, 15, 12, 13, 14, None, 11]])
(1871, 540, 4, [10, [1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 6, 7, 8, 5, 10, None, 12, 13, 14, 15, 11]])
(28203, 555, 3, [9, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, None, 10, 12, 13, 14, 11, 15]])
(28399, 560, 2, [10, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, None, 12, 13, 14, 11, 15]])
(28425, 581, 1, [11, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, None, 13, 14, 15, 12]])
(28483, 582, 0, [15, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, None]])
```

The last line means that after 24,483 experiments it found the target position after 582 moves. Note that 582 is for sure very far from optimal as it's known that no position in the classic version of the 15 puzzle requires more than 80 moves.

The number after the number of moves is the "manhattan distance", for example the fourth-last row is the position:

[image]

where the sum of manhattan distances from the solution is 3.

Comment: I understood the essence of your strategy for solving the puzzle. Though, I don't have any idea about what manhattan distances are, or how to compute them. I will do some research on it before attempting the puzzle again sometime later.

Why do say that Python is not good for this problem? I have read about it being one of the most powerful languages in use today.

Comment: @flamingo_stark: Manhattan distance is simply `abs(x1-x2)+abs(y1-y2)` i.e. the distance needed to travel on a grid when moving only horizontal or vertical. Python is a very very nice language (I love it), but default implementation CPython doesn't shine for speed of execution and you should consider for example that's about 100 times slower than C for general low-level algorithms of numbers and arrays manipulation. The PyPy implementation instead takes it to the level of Javascript, and while still slower than C, is much much faster for this.